# Accessing Method Through Service --- Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

My Controller PurchaseOrder Controller

```
<?php

namespace CJ\BusinessBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use CJ\BusinessBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder;
use CJ\BusinessBundle\Form\PurchaseOrderType;

/**
 * PurchaseOrder controller.
 *
 * @Route("/purchaseorder")
 */
class PurchaseOrderController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Lists all PurchaseOrder entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="purchaseorder")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('CJBusinessBundle:PurchaseOrder')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a new PurchaseOrder entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="purchaseorder_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("CJBusinessBundle:PurchaseOrder:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new PurchaseOrder();
    $form = $this->createForm(new PurchaseOrderType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('purchaseorder_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new PurchaseOrder entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="purchaseorder_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new PurchaseOrder();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new PurchaseOrderType(), $entity);

    $purchase = $this->get('cj.businessbundle.purchase');
    $purchase->newAction();

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a PurchaseOrder entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="purchaseorder_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('CJBusinessBundle:PurchaseOrder')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find PurchaseOrder entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing PurchaseOrder entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="purchaseorder_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('CJBusinessBundle:PurchaseOrder')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find PurchaseOrder entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new PurchaseOrderType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Edits an existing PurchaseOrder entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="purchaseorder_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("CJBusinessBundle:PurchaseOrder:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('CJBusinessBundle:PurchaseOrder')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find PurchaseOrder entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createForm(new PurchaseOrderType(), $entity);
    $editForm->bind($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('purchaseorder_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Deletes a PurchaseOrder entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="purchaseorder_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('CJBusinessBundle:PurchaseOrder')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find PurchaseOrder entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('purchaseorder'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a PurchaseOrder entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
}
```

Serivces.yml

```
services:
   cj.businessbundle.purchase:
      class: CJ\BusinessBundle\Controller\PurchaseController
```

Accessing method inside controller [Not Purchase Controller]

```
$purchase = $this->get('cj.businessbundle.purchase');
$purchase->newAction();
```

Getting error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/cj/public_html/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 163

The new Action does exist

I think I am doing something wrong while defining the service

Comment: can u post class where u invoke $purchase = $this->get('cj.businessbundle.purchase');

Comment: This controller is the class where I invoke it. Its under public function newAction

Comment: I haven't noticed that :) sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `$this->get("your.service")` you are asking the dependency injection container to load that service.  You are requesting that it loads one of your controllers which extends Symfony's controller class which extends [ContainerAware](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html).  The error you are getting is because the loaded controller is likely trying to access a service like "request" using `$this->container->get("request")` but `$this->container` is not set.

ContainerAware has a method `setContainer` which you can actually run when your service is setup by using the `calls:` argument in services.yml:

```
services:
   cj.businessbundle.purchase:
      class: CJ\BusinessBundle\Controller\PurchaseController
      calls:
        - [setContainer, [@service_container]]
```

Symfony2 does this for the loaded controller (PurchaseOrderController) but not if you just load a controller class yourself.

It would be much better practice to extract the newAction (or the required logic) from PurchaseController as a service itself rather than setting the whole controller as a service.  This way both Purchase and PurchaseOrder controllers can call the service to create a new purchase (or whatever newAction does) and you are not loading a whole controller everytime.  Check out the [FOS user bundle user manager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php) for a good example of a service or http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service

Comment: @Luke Thanks a ton man. Hey can you point something that will have me build an ajax form. Like a purchase order form I want to have add option to add new items to it. like add new item button would add fields to form via ajax

Comment: The symfony2 docs have a section on collections and using jQuery (in their example) to add new tags to a task http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.  Not sure if thats what you mean